# iPhone prototype app which overlays mocks with developed screens?

Tags: iphone, mockup, user-experience

Anyone know the name of an app where you can overlay the design mocks on the developed testing screens?

I downloaded an iphone app like this before, but forgot what it was.
It’s hard to for the developer to match the code to the image exactly, so it’d be greatly helpful for find it again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what apps are available on iOS for this purpose, but if you use Shortcuts Macstories keeps an up to date [Apple Frames](https://www.macstories.net/ios/apple-frames-now-with-support-for-the-2020-ipad-air/) shortcut.